# Getting a subset of numpy array indicies an easy way

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix-indexing

Can this `for` loop be written in a simpler way?

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

def f(a, b, c): # placeholder for a complex function
  print(a+b+c)

a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)

for y, x in itertools.product(range(a.shape[0]-1), range(a.shape[1]-1)):
  f(a[y, x], a[y, x+1], a[y+1, x])
```

The other options I tried, look more convoluted, e.g.:

```
it = np.nditer(a[:-1, :-1], flags=['multi_index'])

for e in it:
  y, x = it.multi_index
  f(a[y, x], a[y, x+1], a[y+1, x])
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing the big picture immediately, but wouldn't two for-loops make this neater?

Comment: @nenad.popovic Array `a` is huge, Python loops are slow...

Answer (score 1):

Posting it as an answer, and sorry if this is too obvious, but isn't this simply

```
for y in range(a.shape[0]-1):
     for x in range(a.shape[1]-1):
         f(a[y, x], a[y, x+1], a[y+1, x])
```

Comment: you have an excess ```)``` in ```range(a.shape[1]-1))```

Answer (score 1):

If I use your method I got:

```py
expected = [5, 8, 11, 17, 20, 23]
```

but you can vectorize the computation by generating an array containing the data in a more suitable way:

```py
a_stacked = np.stack([a[:-1, :-1], a[:-1, 1:], a[1:, :-1]], axis=0)
```

From there multiple solutions:

- If you already know the function will be the sum:

```py
>>> a_stacked.sum(axis=0)
array([[ 5,  8, 11],
       [17, 20, 23]])
```

- If you know that your function is already vectorized:

```py
>>> f(*a_stacked)
array([[ 5,  8, 11],
       [17, 20, 23]])
```

- If your function does not vectorize, you can use `np.vectorize` for convenience (no performance improvement):

```py
>>> np.vectorize(f)(*a_stacked)
array([[ 5,  8, 11],
       [17, 20, 23]])
```

Obviously you can flatten the array next.

Comment: Function `f` is just a placeholder for something much more complex. I was looking for the loop options.

Comment: So last option should do the job (for loop under the hood), but you might want to check if you can't vectorize `f` so option 2 can be used, which will be much faster.